# Uber API to provide info if driver is completing a ride before pickup

Tags: uber-api

In the Uber riders app, there is a label displaying if driver is completing a ride before picking me up, with 'Completing a trip nearby'.

Is that info provided in the API somehow?

Comment: The info you requesting is not available in the API currently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you post as a reply so I can upvote answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uber API currently does not provide info 'Completing a trip nearby' if the driver is completing a ride before picking next trip.